# Trying to find the amplitude at the gate of a MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, resonance

[image]

When RLC is in a resonance state that means the total impedance seen by Vs is just Rs. I see no use in this information.

This problem kinda confuses me because there's no current flowing into the gate of this transistor so there would be no voltage drop in Rs so the amplitude at the gate would be the same of signal Vs.

Perhaps if the frequency wasnt the same as the resonance state there would be some flow because of the parasitic capacitance connecting to the source?

Edit, my second attempt:

[image]

Comment: I did considered the rlc a series circuit... in that case how should i approach this? Can you give any suggestion?

Comment: There is a voltage amplitude across reactive components in an RLC circuit -- it's \$I\cdot X_L\$ (resp. \$I\cdot X_C\$ for capacitors) where \$I\$ is the current.

Comment: Why do you think no current is flowing through the gate?

Comment: @glen_geek: Did you mean to write "parallel"?

Comment: _"I see no use in this information."_ - Well, there's your problem...

Comment: @OskarSkog The resonant frequency is sqrt(1/Lg*Cgs) (rads/s) and the current through Rs (and Lg/Vgs) is Us/Rs.

The impedance of the Gate capacitance at that frequency is 1/(j * sqrt(1/Lg*Cgs) *Cgs) = Xc. With this info the voltage at the gate should be (Us/Rs) * Xc.

One thing that i'm not sure is that if the voltage drop in Rs is Us/Rs * Rs = Us then the voltage at the gate would be negative (still need to consider the voltage drop of Lg), but that doesnt go with the voltage drop of Cgs i just shown.

Comment: At resonance the voltage across the capacitance is equal but opposite (180° shifted) to the voltage across the inductance.

Comment: @OskarSkog sorry for me deleting some of my posts here, trying to make things simple. I added an edit to the main post, i believe that's how we compute the voltage at the gate?

Comment: @glen_geek "a *series circuit*? It is not." It looks like one to me. Could you explain your comment?

Comment: Your final formula is correct: \$Vs/Rs\cdot 1/(\omega C)\$ but then you substituted in the inductance instead of the capacitance. I compute 2.918 mV for the final answer.

Comment: @ErikR I think i solved this problem then. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @GrahamNye seems I've run afoul of semantics. I suspected that this RLC was viewed as a two-terminal network because of GOtBlackOps's simple initial approach. It is a 3-terminal network (output across capacitor) that requires a more complex approach.

Comment: @ErikR "I compute 2.918 mV for the final answer." So did I. :-) Well, strictly -j2.918 mV.

Comment: @glen_geek "It is a 3-terminal network (output across capacitor)" It is but the R, L and C still form a series (and series resonant) circuit.